# Java - Searching through a file without using a list

Tags: java, if-statement, input, while-loop, file-handling

I'm trying to create a program that will let a user search through a file for a specific word, without creating an array and adding all the contents of the file to it (so it could be easily ported and used with different file sizes etc). Below is my code:

```
package test2;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Kafaka157
 */
public class Prep2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream stream = Prep1.class.getResourceAsStream("words.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);             

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

        String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input word to look for: ");

        if(word.equals(scanner.next().trim())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + " found"); // found
            break;
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,word + " not found"); // not found
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The above is my code, I get no build errors or anything, however it won't return found on words which I know are in the file. It seems to default to else at every instance, any help / idea where I'm going wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: You are breaking out of your `while` loop in the first iteration. That's what having `break` statements does. And maybe your input dialog should be shown before the loop (unless you want to ask for input repeatedly).

Comment: `scanner.hasNextLine()` probably should be `scanner.hasNext()`.  In general, your read operation should match your check.

Comment: @ khelwood - Yeah, I want it to exit after each iteration / ask each time. I'll add in continue options etc later, but for now it's a one use thing. However the issue is it not reading strings which I know are in the file

Comment: @ VGR - Thanks, I tried with hasNext, but still nothing... It does read the first string, but anything beyond that always returns a not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
InputStream stream = Prep1.class.getResourceAsStream("words.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);             
boolean wordFound = false;//initially set it to false

String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input word to look for: ");

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

    if(word.equals(scanner.next().trim())){
 //after the loop would be a better place to show below notification
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + " found"); // found

        wordFound = true;//make the flag as true and break out of the loop
        break;
    }/*else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,word + " not found"); // not found
        break;
    }*/
}
if(wordFound)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + " found"); // found
else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,word + " not found");
```

Few modifications needed and that should do. The comments provided above should serve the purpose. The main problem is that you are breaking out of the loop after checking the first word itself!

Comment: That's brilliant thank you very much. Clearly a lot yet to learn in regards to Java. Thanks very much for the comments / reply :).